# SharePoint 2013 development video

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, 2013

Can you plz guide me to get a link for a very good Demo video on SharePoint 2013 development? I have downloaded a demo video from CriticalPathTraining but this is not a good one as it describes only slides but does not capture real visual studio development activity. 
I could not find a good one by myself. Plz share a link which shows exclusive 2013 development through visual studio.

Comment: You should really consider accepting some answers to your questions. Out of more than 40, you have only accepted 1 answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is the Microsoft Developer site for SharePoint with a bunch of videos containing a decent amount of theory and practice.

[SharePoint 2013 training for developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/fp123633)

[PluralSight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses) has a number of courses, including a 2013 developer ramp-up from Critical Path. Anything section you see prefixed with `Demo` at PluralSight will usually contain a demonstration of the theory learned in previous sections inside of Visual Studio. You can get a 10 day/200 minute trial to test their services out. At US$29 it's a very good deal. I believe that certain levels of MSDN subscription also come with some sort of voucher for PluralSight but I am not sure of the details. I have had a subscription for two years and cannot recommend it highly enough. It's an excellent resource.

They have a number of courses from SharePoint MVPs like [Rob Windsor](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/111/rob-windsor) ([@robwindsor](https://twitter.com/robwindsor)), Sahil Malik ([@sahilmalik](https://twitter.com/sahilmalik)), and [Andrew Connell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/401/andrew-connell) ([@andrewconnell](https://twitter.com/andrewconnell)).

Other than that just doing a YouTube search for [SharePoint 2013 development](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sharepoint%202013%20development&oq=sharepoint%202013%20development&gs_l=youtube.3..0l3.10983.15839.0.16063.27.19.0.8.8.0.87.1217.19.19.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.AYhVl6rlv3o) yielded results with demos using Visual Studio. But if you want quality training videos, you're going to have to go to a subscription site.

Here are some items I have found

[Visual Studio 2012 Setup For SharePoint 2013](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=yoEAMQhy9vE) `00:4:06` <= **Likely where you should start.**

[Building Your First SharePoint 2013 App With VS 2012—SVNUG](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHkGDJmHxYo) `1:34:00`

[Real-world Apps for SharePoint 2013 - Kudos (Part 1)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=LLXhIjLUs6A) `00:9:50`

[Real-world Apps for SharePoint 2013 - Kudos (Part 2)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=_mTB_b_XcRw) `00:6:31`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sharepoint Server Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/cc707678) 
One of the biggest problems I had when starting Sharepoint was setting up the development machine.These labs provide virtual machines with the whole setup so you can just start trying out the practice exercises.